# Admin interface problems - thickbox? jquery?

Tags: admin

All of a sudden the thickbox functionality in the wordpress admin seems to have died and I'm having a hard time figuring out why that is and how to fix it.

Clicking the featured image button loads the content into the window rather than a modal. Clicking the edit beside 'published' in the 'publish' box does nothing at all (which I recognize isn't thickbox, so I'm thinking it has to be something else).

I'm assuming this is something to do with either jQuery or thickbox, but I'm not sure how to figure out where the problem is and I couldn't find another question with the same errors. Unfortunately it's on the live site (so I can't turn on wp-debug) and when I made a mirror to my local server the problem didn't show up.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Any chance to see a link?

Comment: Not sure that a link to the admin would get you anywhere. I'd have to create a userID, which I'm pretty sure my boss would frown on. :)

Comment: Sorry i meant to the site. Just to check the scripts loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Have you disabled all plug-ins to rule out a jquery conflict?. Do you have any custom scripts that you are registering in your theme? If so are you using: `if( !is_admin()){` to ensure it's not loading on the back-end?

Comment: I can't disable the plugins on the live site unfortunately, and couldn't create the problem on the mirror. I'll check the scripts that were there previous to see if they have if( !is_admin()){. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading you right then it sounds very like something that I've run into after trying to recover a site that had been hacked. In my case I replaced the js file in wp-includes/js/thickbox ( though i cant remember i might have replaced the entire wp-includes directory.) Beware of course that to do this it would be VITAL that you'd get the file(s) from the exact same version of WordPress, and of course backup ( and backup the file you're replacing to have it handy too, so you can quickly go back a step ).

Of course if this works there's a possibility your site had been hacked so you'd probably be looking at restoring from a backup or something.

Comment: Boy, I hope not! I'll take a look at this option tonight.

Comment: I'm sure there are other possibilities too - i didn't mean to alarm you ;-) - it just reminded me of that